# Trying to write the java code from the urlify problem in cracking the coding interview in python

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I took the Java code from cracking the coding interview for the urlify problem (1.3):

URLify: Write a method to replace all spaces in a string with '%20'. You may assume that the string has sufficient space at the end to hold the additional characters, and that you are given the "true" length of the string. (Note: if implementing in Java, please use a character array so that you can perform this operation in place.)

EXAMPLE

Input: "Mr John Smith   , 13

Output: "Mr%2eJohn%2eSmith"

I'm having some issues with the converted code. Here is my python code:

```
def urlify(str, trueLength):
    spaceCount = 0
    index = 0
    i = 0
    for i in range(0, trueLength):
        if str[i] == ' ':
            spaceCount += 1
        print(spaceCount, "spaceCount")
    index = trueLength + spaceCount * 2
    if (trueLength < len(str)):
        str[trueLength] = '\0'
    for i in range(trueLength, 0):
        if str[i] == ' ':
            str[index - 1] = '0'
            str[index - 2] = '2'
            str[index - 3] = '%'
            index = index - 3
        else:
            str[index - 1] = str[i]
            index = index - 1


print(urlify("Mr John Smith     ", 13))
```

I think one of the issues is

```
str[trueLength] = '\0'
```

I'm not sure what else could be an issue. I'm also a little confused about the two lines

```
if (trueLength < len(str)):
        str[trueLength] = '\0'
```

so if someone could explain those lines, that would be awesome. I just wanted to fully understand Gayle's solution.

---

Code I found:

```
def urlify(string, length):
'''function replaces single spaces with %20 and removes trailing spaces'''
new_index = len(string)

for i in reversed(range(length)):
    if string[i] == ' ':
        # Replace spaces
        string[new_index - 3:new_index] = '%20'
        new_index -= 3
    else:
        # Move characters
        string[new_index - 1] = string[i]
        new_index -= 1

return string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shorten code(more Pythonic way):

```
def urlify(string, real_length):
 return string[:real_length].replace(' ', '%20')
```

Explanation:

```
string[:real_length]
# This limits strings to real length, in your case to 13. This will remove unnecessary end of the string. 
.replace(' ', '%20')
# This replaces every space with '%20'.
```

About your code:

1. In Python, 'str' is reserved word. Do not use it.
2. In Python, you can't change strings. You must create new one. String item assignment is not supported. Your code is completely based on item assignment. You should instead create new string and add characters to it.
3. This code is really messed up. It is very hard to understand, you should find easier solution.

Your code and logic optimized:

```
def urlify(string, trueLength):
    new_string = ''
    for i in range(0, trueLength):
        if string[i] == ' ':
            new_string=new_string+'%20'
        else:
            new_string=new_string+string[i]
    return new_string
```

Comment: I think the important part to this question is to use lists because python strings are immutable

Comment: You can use Python strings, but you should always create new instead of changing the old one.

Comment: From the book "We have implemented this problem using character arrays, because Java strings are immutable. If we used strings directly, the function would have to return a new copy of the string, but it would allow us to implement this in just one pass." So maybe it's best to avoid creating a new string altogether

Comment: I don't know about Java but it is perfectly fine to create a new string in Python. Actually, you must create new string once - you can't change old but you must return string, which means that you must create a new one sooner or later. It would be best to use my first example(Pythonic version) but if it is too advanced for you/your class, then you can use second solution. Please, feel free to ask if you don't understand something, I'll explain.

Comment: Also, there is no characters array in Python. Yes, you can create a list with strings but it is not limited to characters and more importantly, it is not built-in type like in Java or C. That means you'll not have any benefits for using it instead of ordinary strings.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping! I do like the first solution you posted but it's a bit advanced at the moment. I just posted a new solution that I found.

Comment: Could you explain how this works because it doesn't look like a new string is created

Comment: As you can see, "new_string='' " creates new string. Then, we just 'inspect' old string and adds characters from old to new string(except spaces, if space is found we add '%20').

Comment: Oh my apologies. I meant I added a new solution at the end of my post. Do you see it?

Comment: To be honest, this code is completely mess + it is even more advanced than my first solution. Do you have any confusions about my second solution? I think it's good for you to use.

Comment: I understand. I will definitely go by your solutions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My guess, justing trying to understand the code you want to understand:

Note that:

> you are given the **"true"** length of the string.

So the `trueLength` can be shorter than the `len(str)`, and you should handle this case in your code.